# Full Width Background Color without compromising font

Tags: html, css, background-color

I’m trying to create a black background section that goes full-screen width. Initially, the black block was getting cutoff based on the parent div so I added the below css. Now the text is no longer adhering to the width of the prior div. Is there an easier way to make the background black and full width for “black-block" without compromising the width of the text within the section? Any help would be great! [image: ( see image)]

```css
.black-block {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="black-block" style="margin-top:10%;background:#1f1f1f;padding-top:10%;padding-bottom:10%">
  <p style="text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:-2%;font-weight:800;color:#3186d2">Design Direction</p>
  <h2 style="color:#ffffff">Focus on developing a lighting solution that is both functional by providing tailored lighting while providing a decorative element.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to put another div inside the black-block

html

```
<div class="black-block" style="margin-top:10%;background:#1f1f1f;padding-top:10%;padding-bottom:10%">
    <div class="container">
        <p style="text-transform:uppercase;margin-bottom:-2%;font-weight:800;color:#3186d2">Design Direction</p>
        <h2 style="color:#fff">Focus on developing a lighting solution that is both functional by providing tailored lighting while providing a decorative element.</h2>        
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.black-block{
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
.container{
    width: 80vw; // or whatever width you're using
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Great! This worked I just needed to add another div inside of black block! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get it but I think you're trying to do this? Just add body and html padding and margin to 0 in your CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/4eg1dv7k/

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if I got your questiong right but if I did, I think that position relative doesn't work with the left & right. Plus those margings might be causing the problem? Again, I didn't quite understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

But does the parent has the screen width? If yes I would recomment using `width: 100%`

`box-sizing: border-box;` will make the element width/height + padding + border to fit the given width/height. (Doesn't work with margin)

Like this?:

```css
body
{
  margin: 0px;
}
.black
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 20px 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `<p>` and `<h2>` elements in another `<div>` that has a different width set to it. Something like this:

```
<div class="black-block">
  <div style="width: 60%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```